# Kitchen Light randomly goes out every ~10 minutes

Tags: lighting, kitchens

For the past few weeks, we've noticed our kitchen track lighting randomly "goes out" every 10 or so minutes. It started out just "flickering" off for a few seconds before coming back on. Sometimes the lights will randomly go to ~1/4 the brightness for a minute or two before going back to full brightness.

Now, It's gotten to the point to where the lights go out completely for 1-2 minutes before coming back on.

I've noticed that nothing else on the kitchen circuit goes out with the lights either -so it must be related to the cheap track lighting.

Could the issue be the transformer for the lights? [Model SL-728](https://www.bonanza.com/listings/Topstar-SL-728-105-Watt-Halogen-Transformer-120V-to-12V-Non-dimmable/514959144?goog_pla=1&gpid=76984044061&keyword=&goog_pla=1&pos=1o1&ad_type=pla&gclid=Cj0KCQjw8MvWBRC8ARIsAOFSVBV5-IDiMcjVkwuBFhknFIvROw9L7VCX5CO3I8Ib7lxmo_SgqZyc6KYaAlheEALw_wcB) If so (not so), what could I test to make sure or determine what the issue is?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Sounds like the common problem of the wrong lightbulb for the fixture which causes excess heat until the thermal override kicks it off, after it cools it comes back on until it overheats and the thermal again kicks it off.  While it could be a transformer issue, it’s usually the bulb wattage causing the problem.

Comment: Yeah I've read up on that - my only concern is the lights have been working perfectly for 2+ years, only to start going on the fritz in the past few weeks.

Comment: This is a low voltage track light system, right? Are your bulbs halogens or LED?

Comment: it needs a 20W min load, which you might not present if you changed the bulbs, which is likely because the required halogens don't last that long...